# HTMLViewer can't display monospaced fonts?

Tags: android, html, fonts

I have an HTML file and it has `<pre style="font-family: 'Courier-New', monospaced;">` around it's contents inside the `<body>` tag.
If I open it with HTMLViewer the font looks like Courier New, but it's not monospaced at all!

Do you have any idea how to get Android's HTMLViewer to render monospaced fonts monospaced?

Comment: if Courier_New will not found then it will apply monospaced font...

Comment: afaik Courier New should be monospaced too...

Comment: Try a browser like opera, firefox, dolphin, chrome...

Comment: problem is that I need to send that file to a printing app that pre-renders using the native Html.fromHtml() method and sends to the printer... but that app isn't mine...
I guess I will have to use RTF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that Android doesn't have Courier New and it's "monospace" font is not really monospaced.
You can add a font to the project's assets but if you want the file to be properly rendered by other applications you would have too root the device.

So basicly, it's impossible to do what I need.
Thanks for the help anyway guys...